# Is it possible to obtain a transit visa and board flights with separate PNRs for travel to Italy and return from Vienna via Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit, europe, india

I have two different PNRs for my flights and I need to travel from India to Italy via Abu Dhabi (Etihad and WizzAir) and return from Vienna to New Delhi via Abu Dhabi (Wizz Air and Etihad). I am wondering if it is possible for me to obtain a transit visa and board my flights given the two separate PNRs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply for such a visa on [Ethiad's](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/visas) website

Ethiad states :

> This facility is open for Guests visiting the UAE travelling on Etihad Airways and Partner Airlines, and also to Guests with valid tickets issued by any Airlines and fulfilling the eligibility conditions announced from time to time by the UAE Authorities.